# NodeJS Connect framework "next()" in custom function

Tags: node.js

My code:

```
module.exports.log = function (message) {
fs.stat(logFile, function (error, stat) {
    if (error) {
        var exception;
        if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
            exception = new Error('File [' + logFile + '] not found.');
            exception.details = { code: 404, reason: 'File not found' };
        } else {
            exception = new Error('Internal sever error - file cannot be delivered.');
            exception.details = { code: 500, reason: 'Internal server error' };
        }
        next(exception);
    } else {
        var stream = fs.createWriteStream(logFile, { flags: 'a' });
        stream.write(message);
        next();
    }
})
};
```

My problem is maybe simple. I would like to have `next()` function in my log function. I don't want to give it as parameter because I will have to always set it in parameter when invoking. Is it possible to have `next()`method inside my function? Maybe some `require()` or anything?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a dedicated logging package like [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

Comment: I am not sure but `morgan` is only middleware. I cant use it in custom functions.

Comment: Then make it an optional argument to your function and only call it when it gets passed.